# CAS and ABA issus

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

we konw the class *java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque* is the CAS implements and

1. i want kown this class is how to solve the ABA problem.
2. i have see the code but it's so hard i can't undstand.

   `public boolean removeFirstOccurrence(Object o) {
           checkNotNull(o);
           for (Node p = first(); p != null; p = succ(p)) {
               E item = p.item;
               if (item != null && o.equals(item) && p.casItem(item, null)) {
                   unlink(p);
                   return true;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou thank you for that clarifcation problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question about ABA problem:

> In garbage collected languages this isn't a problem. Why? Because the
>   node's memory cannot be reclaimed for a new object until observing
>   threads containing pointers to the structure have released them.

(From [here](http://www.hergert.me/blog/2009/12/25/intro-to-lock-free-wait-free-and-aba.html))

In short, destructive ABA scenario occurs when reference at adress `A` first points to one object, then to some another, which may happen when another thread first frees address holding `A`, then re-allocates it to hold reference to another object, while the first thread stucks. In Java, this cannot happen because first thread all the time holds this reference and it thus cannot be garbage collected (freed). It can be reallocated, but after that first thread CAS will expect another (moved) address and fail.

If `A` both times points to the same object, A->B->A by second thread acts like it didn't modify anything, so consistent state (in this case) is not broken.

Comment: if  "In garbage collected languages this isn't a problem. "   why the java have the class : java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicStampedReference<V>  and what state is the class to used.

Comment: @李思聪 stamped reference is used when fact of modification itself is important (i. e. to perform swap action, thread 1 should be guaranteed that *nothing* was made on reference). This is not the case for queue, because such ABA is not critical in this case--it's just like detaching node and attaching *the same node* again.

Comment: "it's just like detaching node and attaching the same node again"   whether it' because this: "UNSAFE.putOrderedObject(this, prevOffset, val);”  ？   what the mean of this 3 params.  (whether it's compare the object address in memory.not the value like int)..  please explanate to me.

Comment: @李思聪 memory address is compared because objects are represented by references, so to find an object you need to find address where reference to this object locates. It's like comparing objects by `==`, not `equals()`--you need *the same* object, not *the copy*.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how this class solves the ABA problem.

The code is just like a single threaded version except;

- p.item reads a `volatile` field.
- all the fields of `Node` are volatile.
- it uses a CAS operation to perform the write `p.casItem(item, null)`
- and retry loop should this fail.

If another thread is modifying the data structure, the CAS will fail and it has to try again.

The CAS operation is both a read and write barrier.

Comment: *"the CAS will fail and it has to try again"*-- it may not fail if another thread concurrently modified the reference two times: from A to B, then from B to A again. Interesting, could this happen in Java--may the different objects be allocated to the same address in short time?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou correct, is this a problem?  If you try to remove object A from the Deque and while attempting to remove it, it is removed and added back in without you noticing. Is it still ok to remove it?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou objects can be allocated to the same address, but not at the same time. The first object allocated to the Eden space after a minor/full GC always has the same address (though not in G1). However, if an object is moved, all its references are updated otherwise lots of assumptions would break, not just here.

Comment: yes, I clearly understand this mechanism (I believe). But imagine the situation: 1) thread 1 reads the reference, sees pointer to A there. It is getting ready to CAS this reference. 2) concurrently, thread 2 updates this reference to pointer B. 3) Then thread 2 creates a *new* object (say, node of a list), which is *accidentally* located at address A, and CASes the reference. 4) thread 1 successfully CASes the reference to some new value, because reference address (A) is unchanged. (this is in short the ABA scenario)

Comment: Now I see this is not possible -- because thread 1 holds reference to initial A pointer, so it cannot be GCd. Any new object will be referenced to some *another* address, so ABA will not occur.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou and if that object is moved and a new object given the same address, the original reference will be changed.  Note: a GC can only occur at a safe point.  This means all byte code instructions are indivisible.

Comment: if the object is moved, then on step (4) CAS will expect another address (moved) and will fail

Comment: @SashaSalauyou .  if Thread2 have chang the A to B and to A  ,well ,the Thread1 will read it agian.because A is validate.... I think it's